# Call Converter Even if Target Property Value is not Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, converters

**Scenario:** I have 2 grid. 1 is parent and 2nd is child. On each row Mouseover i am calling a converter. When record in parent is selected it's subsequent child records are shown in child grid. On mouseover of child row it calls converter.

**Issue:** The issue i'm facing is that multiple parents records could have same child. I want to call converter forcefully when chid is shown for different parent, but when child is same it didn't calls the converter as the target property was not changed.

**Example:** Grid 1 has parent record A and B. Record A has 2 childs.

Record A: 1) Comman Child

Record B: 1) Common Child  2) Record B Child

On Selecting Row A and then onmouseover common child calls the converter. When Record B is selected it calls converter for just Record B Child and not for Common child. As the value is not changed.

**PS:** Childs are placed in ChildsObservableCollection and on the selection filtercollection is filled from childObservableCollection. filtercollection is bounded to child grid.

I know it's default behavior of converter that it is only called when target property value is changed, but here i want to forcefully call the converter on row-binding/changing. Any Idea?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try forcefully update binding target. I've wrote some example with `TextBlock` `tbTest`.

```
<TextBlock Name="tbTest" Text="{Binding TestInt, Converter={StaticResource intToStr}}" />
```

Code behind look like this. `UpdateTarget()` causes `Conveter.Convert` call.

```
var bindingExpression = tbTest.GetBindingExpression( TextBlock.TextProperty );
bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
```